# using GL_MAP2_COLOR_4 inOpenGL to change vertexe colors

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a model in which I store my vertex data to draw a surface, every thing is OK but color of vertexes do not work.

```
GLfloat ctrlpoints[model->rowCount()][model->columnCount()][3];
for (int i = 0; i < model->columnCount(); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < model->rowCount(); ++j) {
        ctrlpoints[j][i][0]=(float)j/model->columnCount();
        ctrlpoints[j][i][1]=(float)i/model->rowCount();
        ctrlpoints[j][i][2]=(float)model->data(model->index(i,j)).toInt();
    }
}
GLfloat ctrlpointsColor[model->rowCount()][model->columnCount()][4];
for (int i = 0; i < model->columnCount(); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < model->rowCount(); ++j) {
        ctrlpointsColor[j][i][0]=1;
        ctrlpointsColor[j][i][1]=0;
        ctrlpointsColor[j][i][2]=0;
        ctrlpointsColor[j][i][3]=1;
    }
}

glEnable(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3);
glEnable(GL_MAP2_COLOR_4);
glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL);
glMap2f(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3, 0, 1, 3*model->columnCount(), model->rowCount(), 0, 1, 3, model->columnCount(), &ctrlpoints[0][0][0]);
glMap2f(GL_MAP2_COLOR_4, 0, 1, 4*model->columnCount(), model->rowCount(), 0, 1, 4, model->columnCount(),&ctrlpointsColor[0][0][0]);
glMapGrid2f(20, 0.0, 1.0, 20, 0.0, 1.0);
glEvalMesh2(GL_FILL, 0, 20, 0, 20);
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? So far you made only a statement (stating something and appending a question mark doesn't make it a question). BTW: OpenGL evaluators have been deprecated for a long time now. If you want to draw curved surfaces, better use a combination of vertex and tesselation shaders.

Comment: The exact question is how to change surface vertex color, the final purpose is having colored surface. In code above, I draw surface but unable to change surface color

Comment: Did you try just setting the color using glColor? I'm not sure why you are uploading an array of just red.

In any event, if you have lighting enabled then I think you also need to enable glColorMaterial. Try disabling lighting.

Comment: thx @Aeluned every things would be OK with your suggestion and glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); Enable color.